# Why in many-to-one direction in relations (C# EF) i always get empty/null data but in oposite direction it's works fine?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Example:

```
public Tim getTim(int userID) 
{
    TimUsers timUser  = _ctx.TimUser.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == userID);
    return _ctx.Times.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == timUser.tim.ID);
}
```

and model (code first) sample:

```
public class TimUsers
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual Tim time {get;set;}
}

public class Tim 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<TimeUsers> timeUsers { get; set; }
}
```

I'm 100% sure that a relation between `TimeUser` and `Tim` exist becouse this method give me a list of `timeUser`:

```
public IQueryable<TimeUsers> GetTimeUsersByTime(int TimeId) 
{
    return _ctx.TimeUser
               .Where(c => c.tim.ID == TimeId)
               .AsQueryable();

}
```

I'm sorry for syntax error but I wrote this sample without debbuging. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the child:

```
var timeWithChildren = _ctx.Times.Include(t => t.time).FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == timUser.tim.ID);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: It define as `virtual` so without `Include` it should be loaded lazily.

Comment: Right, that's why your second query works and the first one doesn't. Isn't this the line not returning the child? return _ctx.Times.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == timUser.tim.ID);

Comment: Sorry, thought that was your comment :)

Comment: ok, so when i change this parametr on true  :  Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; this resolve this problem too?

Comment: Doesn't matter unless you want to use lazy loading. If you have virtual navigation properties you can use lazy loading where the children won't be loaded until referenced. With lazy loading enabled, you need to use include to get them. See the link in the answer for a rundown on scenarios. Personally, I don't use lazy loading unless your dealing with deep object graphs and/or tons of data.